# Adding proptypes to unnamed anonymous default exported functions - e.i "export default () =>{}"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

I know you can do the following:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Header = ({ name }) => <div>hi {name}</div>;

Header.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};

export default Header
```

However can I assign `propTypes` with anonymously exported default functions  (`export default () =>{}`) like the following?:

```
 export default ({ name }) => <div>hi {name}</div>;


 //how do I do this part/ is it possible?
   ?.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string
   };
```

---

EDIT: I tried:

```
    export default ({ name }) => (<div>
//  ----- here ------- (makes sense why, it doesn't work) 
    static propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string
    }
// ---------------
     {name}
    </div>);
```

and:

```
// -------and like this at bottom --------
    default.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string
    }
// ------------------
```

I don't think it is possible, exporting this way, just one of the tried offs on the overall approached.

Comment: i mean... `static` is only for defining static properties of classes, and `default` isn't a variable.

Comment: Simple question: why? There is no value to you, your codebase, and especially future devs/maintainers (including yourself a month from now) in making anonymous components like this. Keep the code easy to read, name your UI components, and then just let bundlers and minifiers take care of the crazy optimizations if and when needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The sane way to do this is to just assign the function to a variable:

```
const anon = ({ name }) => <div>hi {name}</div>;
anon.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};

export default anon;
```

If you truly believe you have a reason not to do it the sane way, how about `Object.assign`?

```
export default Object.assign(
  ({ name }) => <div>hi {name}</div>,
  { propTypes: { name: PropTypes.string } }
);
```

Comment: Object.assign! that's very clever.

Answer (score -3):

Found out how, I could do the following:

```
require('./Header').default.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Where `Header` is the file exported.

Any disadvantages to this approach (is this loading the same file back into memory?)? Don't ever see this pattern in the wild? That probably for a good reason because I'm re-importing it.

Comment: That's a terrible idea, though: that makes _another_ module responsible for _this_ module's propTypes. That doesn't even make sense. (this is basically a variation of the old prototype pollution antipattern)

Comment: yes the disadvantage is that you would have to write that in every file you require it in, right? what would be the point of this?

Comment: no, that's not how nodejs works. `require` uses cached objects, so if you require object A in two modules, and you modify it in the first module, the second module gets that modified copy as well. It basically makes your code magically non-deterministic to human readers.

Comment: oh sure, I guess you could have a single file where you add all the propTypes, assuming it gets loaded first. still insane if you ask me (first as in, if its required dynamically at runtime)